# Elastic search aggregation with range query ignored

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I have a index which indexes a number of products. The price ranges from $1 to $ 100. I want to send 1 request to retrieve the products whose prices are between $1 and $50, and the max price among all products ($100). So I sent 1 request with both range and aggregation query:

```
{
"query": {
        "range" : {
          "price" : {
            "from" : 1,
            "to" : 50
          }
        }
},
"aggs" :{
  "max-price" : {
    "max" : {
      "field" : "price"
    }
  }
}
```

It returned all the products whose prices are between $1 and $50, and the max price of $50 in the aggregation field. How can I make it so that it still returns all the products whose prices are between $1 and $50 but the max price of $100 in the aggregation field, which is the max price of all products ignoring the range query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [post filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.3/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-post-filter) which is applied after aggregation is calculated. Order of calculation: query --> aggregations --> post_filter.

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "max-price": {
      "max": {
        "field": "price"
      }
    }
  },
  "post_filter": {
    "range": {
      "price": {
        "from": 1,
        "to": 50
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So in above first query executes which match all the documents, then on all these documents aggregation is calculated which will give the max price and then filters the result of query documents by the range provided.